# hallar el monto total (de cada orden) que hay por cliente, en donde solo debo considerar por cliente una sola orden (el de mayor monto)

Tags: sql

[image: Esa es la pregunta]

Primero al hacer la consulta:

```
select o.custid, o.orderid, sum(od.unitprice * od.qty) as VentaTotal 
from Sales.OrderDetails as od inner join Sales.Orders as o on od.orderid = o.orderid
group by o.custid, o.orderid order by 1`
```

me arrojar una tabla con varios `custid` iguales,
pero no se como solo mostrar el mayor de cada `custid`

Comment: Sql tiene unas funciones llamadas MAX y MIN que te permiten extraer el máximo o mínimo de una consulta. Checa [esto](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-aggregate-functions/sql-server-max/). Solo debes consultar a un cliente de acuerdo a una orden y usar una de esas funciones.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: usa la clausula Distinct

Comment: qué motor de base de datos estás usando?